# Materialize css select not working with JS errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue with select form using Materialize css framework. This is my form:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('select').material_select();
</script>
```

This is my layout in slim:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta content=("text/html; charset=UTF-8") http-equiv="Content-Type" /
    title Budeprace
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css', media: 'screen,projection'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"

  body
    .container
      - flash.each do |key, value|
        div class=("text-center #{flash_class(key)}") 
          = value

      = yield

      = javascript_include_tag 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js'
      = javascript_include_tag 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js'
```

If I remove the two .js scripts from layout, the SELECT works. If I will remove the two scripts from the form and leave them in layout, the SELECT won't work anymore with following error in browser:

```
"job:65 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function"
```

The error remain even if I will put it to the application.js in this way:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
```

Any idea what is wrong? I went along many select and dropdown problems with materialize but couldn't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your resulting HTML instead of the slim code.

Comment: You can try using `$(document).ready()`

Comment: [Works fine in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdwme3ko/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Materialize is built using jQuery. In this part of your code:

```
  = javascript_include_tag 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js'
  = javascript_include_tag 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js'
```

You're loading the Materialize plugins before you load jQuery itself. Switch the order of those two lines.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to [accept your favorite answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to your questions to encourage others to help you in the future.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The order of CDN was indeed the problem for me. Thanks Blazemonger.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is caused by the version becoming obsolete. I use

```
=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

So it works

Comment: In my case the same: 1.0.0-beta version seamed to be faulty at this point :(

Answer (score 1):

The newer jQuery way to initialize a select dropdown is with

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('select').formSelect();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but the issue was that jquery was loaded after the Materialize library and the library depends on jQuery

Comment: Thank. This works with the latest version of jquery 3.3.1 and Materialize 1.0.0-rc.2